# BaseHTTPRequestHandler cgi.parse_multipart never returns

Tags: python-3.x, xmlhttprequest, multipart, basehttprequesthandler

I have the following snippet in my `do_POST`:

```
            c_type, p_dict = cgi.parse_header(
                self.headers.get('Content-Type')
            )
            content_len = int(self.headers.get('Content-length'))
            p_dict['boundary'] = bytes(p_dict['boundary'], "utf-8")
            p_dict['CONTENT-LENGTH'] = content_len
            postvars = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, p_dict)
```

It continues all the way up until the last `postvars` line, where it just stops. Subsequent requests aren't even processed until I restart the debug process.

For completeness, this is the JS I use to post the `FormData`:

```
    function send() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "URL_WAS_HERE";
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

        };
        var form = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
        xhr.send(form);
    }
```

Other forms  that simply `POST` a `JSON` string work fine, but this needs to be multi-part because I also upload a file in the form. I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code, it looks more or less the same as everybody else's `multipart` handling code for Python 3.

What also could be an interesting lead is that if I try the following in the debug console:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage(
    fp=self.rfile,
    headers=self.headers,
    environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST'})
```

...this debug command also stays stuck forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had read the `rfile` before in a fork I thought I didn't hit. Still weird behavior, I would expect an error instead.

Comment: This is too strange, Thanks for sharing :)) wasted about an hour in this error :(